# SPSS Mean grouped by two variables

Tags: spss

I would like to find the mean of one variable (Health) broken down 2 other variables (Department and Sex)

How can I do this so it shows up in one table?

Comment: do you have the CTABLES module lincesed ?

Comment: No I just have the standard license, Can you do a split within a split?  Any other solution would be great

Comment: Which version of SPSS ?

Comment: Found what I needed it was in the compare means menu option


DATASET ACTIVATE DataSet1.
COMPUTE JobStress=Task+Clarity.
EXECUTE.
MEANS TABLES=JobStress BY Jobtype BY Sex
  /CELLS=MEAN STDDEV.
EXECUTE.

Comment: Your question sounds like you want to break "Health" down by two separate  variables in one table (`x by y, z` and not `x by y by z`). That's why the solution you posted didn't come up sooner. Is your solution sufficient of are you looking for `x by y, z` after all?

Comment: Yes I understand how my question was confusing, the answer I posted is sufficient thank you